# python convert GMT time into KST time

Tags: python, datetime, gmt

I want to get the server time for my ticketing program.
I firstly used

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

But I've noticed that my computer time is not accurate from the real servertime.
So I've tried to get time from google.com [headers]

```
import urllib3

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://google.co.kr/") as response:
     date = response.headers["Date"]
```

reponse:

```
'Tue, 27 Jul 2021 04:41:49 GMT'
```

However, I need "KST" time.
How can I convert "GMT" time into "KST"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datetime.datetime.astimezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) to convert a time to your target timezone (here is a list of the [timezone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)).

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pytz  # or you could try using zoneinfo in Python3.9

dt_utc = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
dt_korea = dt_utc.astimezone(tz=pytz.timezone("Asia/Seoul"))

print(f"dt_utc: {dt_utc}")
print(f"dt_korea: {dt_korea}")
```

Output:

```
dt_utc: 2021-07-27 05:11:54.640773+00:00
dt_korea: 2021-07-27 14:11:54.640773+09:00
```

It doesn't always need to be based from UTC, like in this example:

```
dt_manila = dt_korea.astimezone(tz=pytz.timezone("Asia/Manila"))
print(f"dt_manila: {dt_manila}")
```

Output:

```
dt_manila: 2021-07-27 13:11:54.640773+08:00
```

In case the time you want to convert is from the server response and you need a way to parse it, you can use [python-dateutil.parser.parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse).

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pytz  # or you could try using zoneinfo in Python3.9

response = 'Tue, 27 Jul 2021 04:41:49 GMT'
dt_response = parse(response)
dt_korea = dt_response.astimezone(tz=pytz.timezone("Asia/Seoul"))

print(f"dt_response: {dt_response}")
print(f"dt_korea: {dt_korea}")
```

Output:

```
dt_response: 2021-07-27 04:41:49+00:00
dt_korea: 2021-07-27 13:41:49+09:00
```

Comment: I think you *should* recommend `zoneinfo` ;-) And you can save another import / 3rd party lib by parsing with strptime + directive `"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"`. However, since %Z is kind of unreliable, I suggest to set UTC explicitly (`.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)`).

Answer (score 0):

Something quick and fast which will work

1. Install the following:

```
pip install py-dateutil
pip install requests
pip install pytz
```

2. Code

```
import requests
import dateutil.parser
import pytz

# you can also use any other time server, but this one just works.
resp = requests.get('http://just-the-time.appspot.com/')

if resp.status_code==200:
   date_time_utc = resp.text.strip()
   date_time_kst = dateutil.parser.parse(date_time_utc).astimezone(tz=pytz.timezone("Asia/Seoul"))
   
   print(date_time_utc)
   2021-07-27 06:23:20

   print(date_time_kst)
   2021-07-27 09:53:20+09:00
```